# JavaScript Array Push key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Ok, I'm going a little wrong here and I've already wasted an hour with this so hopefully one of you guys can help me.

```
var a = ['left','top'],
    x = [];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    x.push({
        a[i] : 0
    });
}
```

How do I go about pushing a value to each of the keys inside the `var a` array?

You can see my failed attempted but hopefully that will give you an insight into what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to use bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj[a[i]] = 0;
x.push(obj);
```

The result will be:

```
x = [{left: 0}, {top: 0}];
```

Maybe instead of an array of objects, you just want one object with two properties:

```
var x = {};
```

and

```
x[a[i]] = 0;
```

This will result in `x = {left: 0, top: 0}`.

Answer (score 8):

You may use:

- [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [**`Array.prototype.reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [**`Arrow functions`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [**`Comma operator`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

---

To create array of objects:

```
var source = ['left', 'top'];
const result = source.map(arrValue => ({[arrValue]: 0}));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var source = ['left', 'top'];

const result = source.map(value => ({[value]: 0}));

console.log(result);
```

---

Or if you wants to create a single object from values of arrays:

```
var source = ['left', 'top'];
const result = source.reduce((obj, arrValue) => (obj[arrValue] = 0, obj), {});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var source = ['left', 'top'];

const result = source.reduce((obj, arrValue) => (obj[arrValue] = 0, obj), {});

console.log(result);
```