# Different ways to push

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have the following array and three vars:

```
array1 = ['']

    dateOutput = 1/1/14
    timeOutput = 12am
    tallysave = 100
```

I was using this to push in the three vars on a push

```
array1.push(dateOutput + ', ' + timeOutput + tallysave)
```

However how can I push each of the vars into the array so they will be like this when pushed: (multi-dimensional array?)

```
array = [
        { "date": dateOutput, "time": timeOutput, },
    ];
```

Comment: That is not a multidimensional array. It is an array with an object as its only value. It would be something like `array1.push({ "date": dateOutput, "time": timeOutput })`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813374/javascript-array-push-key-value

Answer (score 0):

You can push the data as an object:

```
array1.push({
   "date": dateOutput, 
   "time": timeOutput 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1.push({ "date": dateOutput, "time": timeOutput})
```

or

```
array1.push([dateOutput, timeOutput])
```

But in the second way you should know that dateOutput with index 0, and timeOutput with index 1

Comment: The second would be `array1[0][0]` to get dateOutput.