# Appending to an object - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I do the following,

```
var array = [];
array['foo'] = [];
console.log(array.length)   // => 0
```

the console.log prints 0 length.

Is there a way to push key-value to arrays in javascript? Is it a bad idea in general? Do I need to keep the length updated myself?

There is the option to use bracket notation as recommended here ([SO - JavaScript Array Push key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813374/javascript-array-push-key-value)).

But later in the code I want to push to the object/array and SO recommends to use arrays again ([SO - Appending to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617036/appending-to-an-object)).

So I'm not quite sure which datastructure to use. For my task I guess I need key-values. Its an async-task and I can't rely on the order in an unnamed array. But from what I read so far, it seems kind of a hack to append to objects, too.

Comment: `length` only counts the numeric array elements, not named properties.

Comment: Usually named properties are used on objects, and arrays just have numeric indexes. Why are you trying to put properties on an array?

Comment: `For my task I guess I need key-values.` Then use an object. Otherwise you'll need to expand your question to show us what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @Bamar The data gets filled async, so I thought its the better way to access the right value later on.

Comment: you should use as an object for key-value ; for checking length (number of prop.) check http://jsfiddle.net/maio/k8wz7862/

Comment: Is there a way to "push" to an object?

Comment: obj-properties don't have an index(like array entries) just a key

Comment: @Stefan: What do you mean? You "push" to an object using the bracket notation exactly how you have it `myObj[key] = value`. You question really isn't clear as to what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Stefan: in technical terms you cannot "push" to an object. "Push" is only for arrays. You can "set" properties of an object. If you want to get a list of all the properties in an object you can do `Object.keys(obj)` which will give you an array of the keys. You can then do `Object.keys(obj).length` to get the number of keys in the object, if that's what you're asking for?

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes, you are right. That was a stupid question. I guess thats then the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push an object:

```
var arr = [];
var obj = {foo: "bar"};
arr.push(obj);
arr.length; //1
arr[0].foo; //"bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a javascript `object`, which acts as a key/value pair data structure (like a `HashMap` or a `Dictionary`).

```
var data = {
  key: 'value'
}

data['key'] // 'value'
Object.keys(data).length // 1
```

For the sake of your future self, you should not add properties to an array nor try to simulate an array with an object.