# How to give a custom name to the objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an upload form and for adding and deleting the files in a filelist I created an array that contains the files to send them in one request.

Creating the array

```
var filelist = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++){
   filelist.push(data.files[i]);
   console.log(filelist);
}
```

Result in console

```
[File, File, File]
```

The files are contained in the array but now I want to give the names in the array the names of the files for deleting purposes.

So instead of [File, File, File], I would like to have for example [image01.jpg, image02.jpg, image03.jpg]

I have already tried

```
filelist.push(data.files[i].name);
```

result

```
["image01.jpg", "image02.jpg", "image03.jpg"]
```

But the files aren't added to the array? Can anybody help me with this please?
The reason I'm doing this is because I would like to try to remove files from the array on value and not on index.

code for deleting the files from the array

```
var idx = filelist.indexOf(file.name);
filelist.splice(idx,1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Array Push key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813374/javascript-array-push-key-value)

Comment: JavaScript arrays have numeric keys. That is, the keys to the entries are `0`, `1`, `2`, and so on. If you want general string keys, use a plain object.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the name of the file as a key:

```
var filelist = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
   var file = data.files[i];
   filelist[file.name] = file;
}
```

And then use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to delete the file based on its name:

```
var filename = fileToDelete.name;
delete filelist[filename];
```

Comment: You can indeed do this, but then you're not using the array as an array and it might as well be a plain object. If you use an array and try to serialize it in anyway (say, as a parameter in an ajax call), this won't work.

Comment: Result of your possible solution is[Serene-Video-232.jpg: File, Serene-Video-233.jpg: File] But it doesn't delete the file from the array

Comment: @DC2015 this is how your console prints out the key value pairs. But, like Pointy points out, you might as well make `filelist` a JavaScript object.

Comment: at John Bupit: It works but as "Pointy" mentioned it doesn't work as a parameter in an ajax call. at Pointy: Do you maybe have an alternative?